# Angular TypeError cannot set property 'Data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my code, I am calling this operation in ngOnInit to be able to see previously edited data when the page reopens. `StickerData` is a property of IStickerData which is an interface. I keep getting

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'StickerData' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next (sticker-preview.component.ts:54)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FinallySubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at FinallySubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at CatchSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at CatchSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
```

error on `subscribe((response: any) => this._stickerData.StickerData = response);` when I open the page. What am I missing here?

TS:

```
private _stickerData: IStickerData;
Filter: IFilter;

@Input()
  set StickerData(prm: IStickerData) {
      if (this._stickerData != prm) {
          this._stickerData = prm;
      }
  }
  get StickerData(): IStickerData {
      return this._stickerData;
  }

 ngOnInit() {
    this._productionService.getStickerDataList(this.Filter)
    .subscribe((response: any) => this._stickerData.StickerData = response);
    
  }
```

service TS:

```
getStickerDataList(data: IFilter): Observable<IStickerData[]> {
        return this._http.post("Production/GetStickerDataList", data);
    }
```

Comment: did you try to debug your code to see what is `undefined` ? And why `GET` method is `POST` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variable before accessing it's properties.

```js
private _stickerData: IStickerData = Object.create(null);
```

And it looks like at the moment the variable `this.Filter` is also left undefined before sending it to the service.

Comment: Thank you I initialized both of them but, the error still continues am i missing something else?

Comment: Try `this._stickerData = { ...this._stickerData, StickerData: response }` instead of directly assigning the property.

Comment: It actually gave the following error in VS Code;
`No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'IStickerData' is not assignable to parameter of type '(error: any) => void'.
      Type 'IStickerData' provides no match for the signature '(error: any): void'`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `this._stickerData.StickerData = [...]` but `this._stickerData` is not initialized, thus it has the value `undefined`.

You may want to add a default value with:

```js
private _stickerData: IStickerData = {};
```